# Data is retrieved from DB but wont insert?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So when I want to retrieve data and check it i.e. if the email already exist echo already registered. That part works fine, however inserting the same data does not work. Are my conditionals ordered improperly? 
(intentionally left out values for the dbhostname id pw variables)

```
$dbname = "hw2";

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhostname, $dbuserid, $dbpassword, $dbname);

$firstname = $_POST["signup-firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["signup-lastname"];
$email = $_POST["signup-email"];
$password = $_POST["signup-password"];
$repassword = $_POST["signup-repassword"];

if ($password != $repassword){
    echo "<br><h3>Passwords did not match. <br>Please try again.</h3>";
}

else {

$ret_email = "SELECT * FROM hw2 WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $ret_email);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0){
    echo "This email is already registered.";
    }   

    else{
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO hw2 (firstname, lastname, email, password, repassword) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password', '$repassword')";
    echo "$insert_query";
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out the actual mysqli_query() call as well :)? What's returned there? Have you tried the query(since you're echoing it) using a database client, to skip the PHP step? If it works in the db client it might tell you things.

Comment: Perhaps this is my lack of mysqli knowledge, however it doesn't look like you're ever executing `$insert_query`. You define it as a string and then echo it, without ever running it.

Comment: Just an observation/warning - please note you're opening yourself up to a SQL injection attack by creating dynamic sql commands like this - consider someone entering the email value '; drop table hw2;' or similar.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! I'm not concerned about SQL injection at the moment since this is just a homework assignment and everything is running on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform the query  not only echoing it

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) 

if ($num_rows > 0){
echo "This email is already registered.";
}   

else{
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO hw2 (firstname, lastname, email, password, repassword) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password', '$repassword')";

echo "$insert_query";
mysqli_query($link,$insert_query)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was what I was missing. I didnt realize I wasnt executing the query. I thought I had but I guess all I did was execute the query and set it equal to a variable. Im guessing I had to do it again?